# NuGet restore in Azure Functions is not working when functions are uploaded as zip files via the Kudu API

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We create FunctionApps through ARM templates and upload the functions using Kudu API as shown below,

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=(“Basic {0}” -f $base64AuthInfo)} `
                    -Uri "<funcappURI>/api/zip/site/wwwroot" `
                    -Method Put `
                    -InFile "function.zip" `
                    -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Though the function gets created, the zip upload is not triggering a NuGet restore, which is causing the function to fail.

Only a manual change in the project.json file is triggering a restore.

Is there any way to trigger a nuget restore, without involving any manual step?

Answer (score 1):

That is not currently supported, and is tracked by this issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/312. Feel free to comment on the GitHub issue add your scenario to it.